# ggplot2 geom_polygon is not plotting anything

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot some triangles in ggplot using geom_polygon but, even though I don't get any errors, the plot is completely empty.

I followed the code given in the documentation to get the same type of data but it does not really help (first example here https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_polygon.html). I'm sure I'm missing some key step in the formatting of the dataframe but I don't understand where I'm wrong.

```
data = read.table(text = "
start end av y1 y2 y3
719000 721000 720000 1 1 2
1199000 1201000 1200000 1 1 2
3039000 3041000 3040000 1 1 2
3679000 3681000 3680000 1 1 2
4119000 4121000 4120000 1 1 2
4999000 5001000 5000000 1 1 2", sep = " ", stringsAsFactors = F, header = T)

ids <- factor(paste(1:nrow(data), 1:nrow(data), sep = "."))

positions <- data.frame(
  id = rep(ids, times = nrow(data)/2),
  x = c(data$start, data$end, data$av),
  y = c(data$y1, data$y2, data$y3)
)

values <- data.frame(
  id = ids,
  value = 1:length(ids)
)

datapoly <- merge(values, positions, by = c("id"))

ggplot(datapoly, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_polygon(aes(fill = value, group = id))
```

Why do I get nothing? Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you,
Valentina

Comment: They're there, they're just very very skinny. Your x scale spans more than 4 million, but each polygon is much less wide. For example, the last one has a width of only 2000, so it only covers 0.048% of the width of the x-axis, so all you can see is what looks like a single vertical line.

Comment: The problem is already mentioned by @camille, you can see that your code works by facetting on the `id` variable: `ggplot(datapoly, aes(x = x, y = y, group = id)) + 
  geom_polygon() + 
  facet_grid(~id,  scales="free")`

Comment: Thank you very much @camille and @CodeNoob!! Now I feel very stupid ><

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to close your polygon:

```
datapoly <- merge(values, positions, by = c("id"))
datapoly2<-rbind(datapoly,datapoly[1,])
datapoly2$id<-as.character(datapoly2$id)
datapoly2[19,1]<-"6.7"
library(ggplot2)
ggplot( datapoly2, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_polygon()
```